# Emulate Nvidia Shield Tablet on Android Virtual Device

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, unreal-engine4

Is there anyway that I can import hardware configurations for nvidia shield tablet to AVD? I'm trying to test a build for an unreal engine game on it.